# How can I optimize lattice constants (celldm) in Quantum espresso?

Tags: quantum-computing

How can I optimize lattice constants (celldm) in Quantum espresso? I want to choose the best celldm for my unit cell of two carbon atoms.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword needed for optimising lattice constants is

```
calculation='vc-relax'
```

which should be put inside the &control block. vc stands for variable cell.